# How is `cp -R` different from CTRL-C/CTRL-V?

Tags: filesystem, copy-paste, fat32

My system is OS X El Capitan 10.11.5. I copied from my OS X Extended filesystem to FAT32 about 30 Gb files by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Now, I received a proposal to do it by `cp -R`.

I am wondering how different it is from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

---

How is `cp -R` different from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>?

Comment: I do not think they are any different except one is more user-friendly than the other if one is not all that familiar with all the command line stuff; not a lot of people know how to interact with computers through shells nowadays.

Comment: I need little more extensive answer because of the large amount of files which I copied. I want to know how similar chose two commands are.

Comment: When copying that large amount of data, `rsync -aP` is probably better as it can be resumed if interrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copying and pasting via Finder there is certain meta-data that is maintained that when using
 `cp -R` it's not.

An example is when copying and pasting via Finder the created/modified date/time stamp of individual files are maintained to that of the existing meta-date vs. using `cp -R` where both the created/modified date/time stamp are set to the date/time of the copy operation.

On directories when copying and pasting via Finder the created date/time stamp is maintained to that of its current value and the modified date/time stamp is set to the date/time of the copy operation. vs. using `cp -R` where both the created/modified date/time stamp are set to the date/time of the copy operation.

Now if you use `cp -aR` the created date/time stamp is set to the date/time of the copy operation and the modified date/time stamp is maintained to it value it had at the time of the copy operation.

In essence copying and pasting via Finder maintains all meta-data attributes that are supported by the destination filesystem and to get the most possible meta-data attributes maintained using `cp` then additional *options* must be used.  Have a look at the `cp` man page for additional command line *options*.

FAT32 does not support all of the file attributes that HFS+ does, however copying via Finder preserves more then `cp` regardless of the *options* implemented.

Comment: Is `cp -aR` equivalent to CTRL-C/CTRL-V in Finder?

Comment: So you need at least `cp -paR` where `-p` preserves modificationTime/accessTime/fileFlags/fileMode/userID/groupID. I do not see any other option that could preserve something.

Comment: `-a` is the same as `-pPR` actually. Also, `cp` *does not* copy any Finder comments stored in the *top* folder of the source hierarchy (which is due to the fact that comments are stored in a `.DS_Store` file in the same parent folder), Ctrl-C/V will. Both options *do* copy Finder comments on objects below the top folder.

Comment: @patrix I want to follow symbolic links. Is `cp -paR` correct one for that? I think option `-a` is not then suitable because it includes `-P`.

Comment: @masi Read the man page for `cp` :-) But symlinks are a tricky beast anyway if you copy whole directory hierarchies, so you probably need to fix some of them manually afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

cp and rsync have a lot of options that modify which attributes (ownership, unix permissions, POSIX ACLs, resource forks in some cases!) will be/will not be transferred/reset, and how certain types of files will be included/excluded, and how links to files or directories will be handled(copying the link vs copying what it points to). It is unlikely that just using -R will get the same behaviour as what you are doing with Finder.

Also: In Finder, you can only directly select things to copy *that you can see* OR which are inside a folder (or anywhere in the subfolder tree of it) that you can see and that you explicitly selected. Depending on your settings that could exclude anything prefixed with "." , and probably some other structures that Finder treats as special.

Comment: You say that Finder ignores .dot files if they are not visible, but `cp -R` not.

Comment: @Masi, In Finder, _the default is to not show hidden Files/Folders_, with the default set, if you copy a Folder which contains hidden objects, all hidden objects within are copied when pasted. If you select individual files the associated hidden dot files are copied & pasted as well, however non-associated dot files and other hidden objects are not copied & pasted via Finder in the later scenario. To copy & paste non-associated hidden objects at the individual level, when not selecting a Folder, those objects must be made visible in order to be selected and thus pasted after a copy operation.

Comment: @Masi `ls -a` will show dot files. Just FYI.